# How can I draw multiple resizable lines at once?

Tags: python, loops, kivy, line, resizable

I am trying to make a notebook application that emulates ruled notebooks. As such, my starting point is to draw a vertical red line on the left and 27 horizontal blue lines that make the writing area. However, I wanted the blue lines to divide the page evenly so my application would look more like a real ruled notebook.
It is for this that I want to know a way to make a loop inside the kv file where I can put resizable lines.
I tried using a for loop using the on_parent command on my kv file, but it seems that when I add a line with self.canvas.add(Line(points, width)) it does not make the line resizable. I can see this because when I increase the size of my window the blue lines inside the for loop remain the same.
As such, I just wanted to know of a way to make a loop with the kv syntax instead of embedding python code in my kv file.

The following is the code of my Python file named main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.graphics import Color


class MyRelativeLayout(RelativeLayout):
    pass

class NotebookApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyRelativeLayout()


NotebookApp().run()
```

and this is the code of my kv file named notebook.kv

```
MyRelativeLayout:

<MyRelativeLayout>:
    RelativeLayout:
        size:root.size
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 0
            Line:
                width: 1.25
                points: (self.width * 0.10, self.y, self.width * 0.10, self.height)
            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 1
            Line:
                width: 1.25
                points: (self.x, self.height * 0.8637, self.width, self.height * 0.8637)
        on_parent:
            for i in range(1, 28): self.canvas.add(Line(points=(self.x, root.height*(i/28), root.width, root.height*(i/28)), width=1.25))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the method `on_parent` to `on_size`. (Before that you have to import the `Line` in `kvlang` as `#: import Line kivy.graphics.Line` if you haven't already.)